# Control order of result from approx()

Tags: r

Both
    `approx(c(-10, 0), c(-10, 0), n = 3)`
and
    `approx(c(0, -10), c(0, -10), n = 3)`
yield the same result, but I feel the second one should return points from (0, 0) to (-10, -10) in that order (i.e. the reverse of what is returned).

Does anyone know the rationale behind the reordering of these results and does anyone have an elegant way of ensuring the ordering matches the input arguments?

To clarify, I would like `approx(c(0, -10), c(0, -10), n = 3)$x` to give the result `0  -5  -10` and not  `-10  -5   0` as is the actual case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no requirement that `x` values are monotone, so `approx` needs to sort them.  If you want to keep values in a particular order, use `approxfun` instead and evaluate it at points in the order you like:

```r
x <- c(0, -10)
y <- c(0, -10)
approxfun(x,y)(seq(x[1], x[2], length.out = 3))
#> [1]   0  -5 -10
```